# Catch js parsing error in header script

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm using a basic loader to load some js on demand in my pages. On one or two machines (I don't have access to those machines) I'm getting errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in xxx", or "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Of course the source files are ok and this is working on thousands of clients. For sure this must be some antivirus that it is modifying my js files, but I want to know what's happening to see if I can prevent or at least notify the client about this.

My problem is that I'm loading the scripts using XMLHttpRequest, and onload I'm attaching the text into the header, like

```
request.onload = function () {
    var txt = request.responseText + "\n//# sourceURL=" + file + "\n";
    try {
        var script = domDocument.createElement("script"),
        head = domDocument.head || domDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

        script.defer = true;
        script.text = txt;
        head.appendChild(script);
    } catch (e) {
        domWindow.onerror("Error loading js.", file, 0, 0, e, txt);
    }

    request.onload = function () { };
};
```

Where "file" points to the file on the server. The thing is, that the catch never executes as the browser seems to happily execute the above code and THEN parse/throws the actual error.

I would like to know if I can, in some way, catch the error inside my loading script so I can report back what the browser really received instead of my js.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to load the scripts and insert them as text into the head?  It would be much better to add script tags with an `src` attribute.

Comment: Yes, because I need to know when the script has been loaded, as the loader may need to load several scripts that are inter-dependant

Comment: onload will do exactly that. You're better off using default methods, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

`try catch` alone can not catch syntax errors, which occur on parsing time. As far as I know, the only way to catch a syntax error is to use `eval`.

```
try{
  var txt = request.responseText + "\n//# sourceURL=" + file + "\n";
  eval(txt);
  var script = domDocument.createElement("script"),
  head = domDocument.head || domDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

  script.defer = true;
  script.text = txt;
  head.appendChild(script);
}catch(er){
  console.log(er);
}
```

I don't recommend this approach. It's better to just load the script file via its url then listening to the `error` events on both the `script` tag and `window` object;

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error){
  console.log(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error);
}
var script = domDocument.createElement("script"),
  head = domDocument.head || domDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

script.defer = true;
script.onerror = function(er){
  console.log(er);
};
script.onload = function(){
  console.log('script loaded');
};
script.src = '/path/to/script.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Mmm... while I can't do that as I need to know when the script has been loaded, maybe I can attach the onerror handler to my script tag. Will try, but do you think that would work?

Comment: @CheloXL You can also listen to `load` event to check if the script is loaded. I've updated my answer for this change. About your idea, I think it won't work.

Comment: Tried your first approach. onerror is never fired. Also, onload always gets fired (script ok or script not ok). Tried on Chrome and FF.

Comment: Just to expand on my previous comment: onerror seems to only get fired when the browser can't download the script. If there are no problems downloading it (even if you serve garbage), only the onload gets executed.

Comment: @CheloXL My bad. You actually also need to listen to the `error` event on `window` object to catch errors from the loaded scripts. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm already listening to that event, and that's how I know there is an error in a script. What I would like to know is what's the browser receiving that ends in a parser error.

Comment: @CheloXL Then you can check all the arguments of `window.onerror` for more details. Take a look at this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#Notes